# Why does checking whether a folder exists using -d on an empty string return true?

Tags: bash

I was writing some scripts and wrote something like

```
ARTIFACTS="/SOME/PATH"
[ -d $ARTIFCATS ] && rm -rf $ARTIFACTS/*
```

What happened is that out of stupidity I executed the second line without executing the first. It turned out that [ -d "" ] returns true and the expression became

```
rm -rf /*
```

Luckily it was only a test machine and I wasn't a sudo, but though I lost some data

My question is, why [ -d "" ] return true?? the documentation clearly states it checks whether a path exists and is a folder

I solved the problem by using

`[ -e $ARTIFACTS ]`
which seems to work

Cheers

Comment: Or maybe you executed both lines. In the code example above, you never set ARTIFCATS.

Comment: I would just write that as `rm -rf $ARTIFACTS` without the `/*`. This would also delete the `$ARTIFACTS` directory, which is fine, because if i want to be sure that it exists before putting something in it, i will execute `mkdir -p $ARTIFACTS` anyway. It will also delete hidden files inside `$ARTIFACTS`, which is also fine, because i wouldn't write `rm -rf $ARTIFACTS/*` if `$ARTIFACTS` contained *anything* i wanted to save.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström very true

Answer (score 9):

1.
These two tests return *true*:

```
# [ -d ] && echo true || echo false
true
# [ -d $SOME_UNSET_VAR ] && echo true || echo false
true
```

according to POSIX (as explained by @Tim).

2.
But this returns *false* (**not** *true* as stated in the question)

```
# [ -d "" ] && echo true || echo false
false
```

because `test` is called with two arguments (although the second one is an empty string).

3.
That's why it is good practice to use `[[ … ]]` instead of `test` (`[ … ]`), which most (all?) current shells provide. This construct checks if you supply enough arguments (otherwise throws an error and aborts)

```
# [[ -d ]] && echo true || echo false
bash: unexpected argument `]]' to conditional unary operator
bash: syntax error near `]]'
```

or simply behaves like one would expect:

```
# [[ -d $SOME_UNSET_VAR ]] && echo true || echo false
false
```

4.
And, as pointed out by @Gilles, even more important is to double quote substitutions. So `-d "$SOME_UNSET_VAR"` expands to `-d ""` and returns *false* even with `test` (equal to case 2). Hence this is also compatible with the Bourne shell `sh`:

```
# [ -d "$SOME_UNSET_VAR" ] && echo true || echo false
false
```

*tested with bash 3.00.16(1) and 4.1.5(1)*

Comment: Bash, ksh and zsh provide `[[ … ]]` but not plain `sh`. The really important practice is to [put double quotes around command substitutions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes): `[ -d "$ARTIFACTS" ]`.

Answer (score 6):

This question has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425663/linux-shell-test-d-on-empty-argument) on StackOverflow.
It says that according to the POSIX standard, `test` should always return successful if it is called with exactly one non-empty argument (and no other arguments).

This should also be the case with `test -e` (and in fact it is on my system), so be careful.

Instead use:

```
[ -d "$ARTIFACTS" ]
```

`test` will then be called with two arguments even if the variable is empty and return false in this case.

Comment: "exactly one nonempty argument." - this is a misleading summary - the page you linked mentions being called with exactly one argument and that argument being non-empty; nothing about the case of a nonempty argument followed by an empty one. The correct solution should be to surround the variable name in quotes.

Comment: @Random832 Thank you! I implemented both of your suggested changes.

Comment: `[ ! -z $ARTIFACTS ] && [ -d $ARTIFACTS ]` is no better: it only caters for the particular case when `$ARTIFACTS` is empty, but fails when `$ARTIFACTS` may contain whitespace or `\[?*`. `[ -d "$ARTIFACTS" ]` is the correct way to do it (or `[[ -d $ARTIFACTS ]]` in shells that have `[[ … ]]`).

Comment: @Gilles You are right, I removed it.Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

> I solved the problem by using [ -e $ARTIFACTS ] which seems to work

You are **wrong**.  It works because `$ARTIFACTS` is now set to something.

When a variable isn't set, then saying

```
[ -d $SOMEVAR ]
```

or

```
[ -e $SOMEVAR ]
```

would **both** evaluate to `true` because it implies saying

```
[ -d ]
```

and

```
[ -e ]
```

respectively.  (Saying `[ foobar ]` would always evaluate to true.)

Saying

```
set -u
```

comes in handy in such situations.  `help set` would tell you:

```
  -u  Treat unset variables as an error when substituting.
```

Comment: [ -e "" ] && echo "PRINT SOMETHING" does not print anything, so how can this be wrong?

Comment: ahh crap [ -e $ARTIFACTS ] with empty artifacts yields [ -e ] not [ -e "" ], got it

Answer (score 4):

See that you set the variable ARTIFACTS and you were checking for ARTIFCATS. Probably mistyping?

Anyway, -d as well as -e would produce same results on unset variables.

Hence **use double quotes** and it will help you.

```
ARTIFACTS="/SOME/PATH"
[ -d "$ARTIFACTS" ] && rm -rf -- "$ARTIFACTS/"*
```

NOTE: If your "/SOME/PATH" has any folder with space, the script you mentioned will break with "binary operator expected" error.

Example:

```
ARTIFACTS="/home backup/"

1) [ -d $ARTIFACTS ] && rm -rf $ARTIFACTS/*
bash: [: /home: binary operator expected

2) [ -d "$ARTIFACTS" ] && rm -rf "$ARTIFACTS"/*
```

will do fine. Don't forget to put quotes in the `rm` invocation as well (`rm -rf $ARTIFACTS` would cheerfully remove `/home` then complain about `backup/*` not existing).

Also, including `-L` check will make sure that it is a directory and not just a symbolic link to a directory.

So, basically,

```
[ -d "$ARTIFACTS" && ! -L "$ARTIFACTS" ] && rm -rf -- "$ARTIFACTS"/*
```